# php include with double quotes generate and error

Tags: php, syntax, include, double, quotes

I transfer my php project from php hosting A (plesk) to php hosting B (cpanel). On php hostingA work fine. php version is 7.4

On php hostingB the project display syntax error:  **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/hostname/public_html/pagename.php on line 1**

On line 1 there is this code with double quotes: `<?php include("connect.php"); ?>`
If replace with this code with single quotes work fine:  `<?php include('connect.php'); ?>`

I noticed some strange behavior: when I restore the double-quoted code, it works fine.
Can you tell me if I can apply a configuration in php.ini to accept double quotes ?

Comment: There is no such "configuration", single and double quotes should work exactly the same way here (since the value does not contain any characters that would be considered an escape sequence in either version.) And why this would raise an error talking about a `}`, can also not be told from the information we have so far.

Comment: The problem is FileZilla. Upload the files with errors. But reuploading files with WinSCP the system work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easy. In a first time, to transfer files i use FileZilla and this upload file with error.

The files reuploading with WinSCP, the errors is fixed and work fine.